# C#: Consuming RabbitMQ Messages on Web Server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm using the C# Client for RabbitMQ.
Many examples use `Console.ReadLine()` or `while(true)` for keeping the connection open to consume messages.
`while(true)` will burn the CPU and `ReadLine()` isn't really applicable on a web server.

I'm using Asp.Net Core Web Service and trying to write some tests for it.
In my Server's Startup method, I call this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (IConnection connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    // configuring queue etc....
                    options.DeclareConsumer(queueName, MessageReceived);

                    ResetEvent.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm not awaiting this task anywhere. Of cause I want my webserver to still serve requests.

In my integration test I would then be able to stop the thread with `MailMessageQueue.ResetEvent.Set();` what I don't need if I dont block but is helpful if I have to block..

I'm somewhat confused if I should block or not, how many threads I need etc.
Is there a useful example somewhere?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In console applications, if you don't put something like `Console.ReadLine` - the process will terminate when it exits main thread (not always, but that's not the point here). This is not the case in web server applications, like asp.net (or rather - you should not bother about that, since it is not handled by you). Because of that - you don't need to start new thread and then block in by waiting - it just does nothing useful and consumes one thread.

Because rabbit consumer already runs on separate thread internally, just remove your using blocks and create connection and channel in main thread:

```
class MailMessageQueue : IDisposable {
    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _channel;

    public void Start() {
        _connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = connection.CreateModel();
        // configuring queue etc....
        options.DeclareConsumer(queueName, MessageReceived);
    }

    public void Stop() {
        _channel.Dispose();
        _connection.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Stop();
    }
}
```

When you are done (that is when before you would signal your event) - just dispose you queue.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Will try this, looks promising :)